# The PHP extension "apcu" must be installed and loaded in order to use the APCu backend

Tags: php, typo3-7.6.x, pecl

I got the error

> "The PHP extension "apcu" must be installed and loaded in order to use
>   the APCu backend"

in TYPO3.

Then I tried to install apcu by the following command.

```
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config

sudo pecl7.2-sp install apcu
```

On executing second command I got the error

> "sudo: pecl7.2-sp: command not found".

Anyone please help me to solve this..

Comment: Wasn't APC the predecessor to the current built in OpCache.  Is it even a thing in PHP7?  I forget.

Comment: Im doing upgradation of an existing typo3 site.It use the older version typo3 7.6. I think it need the APC. Im a beginnner. I dont have well knowledge in php.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to run `pecl7.2-sp` instead of  just `pecl`? In any case, you need to have that utility installed just like all the rest (gcc, make, autoconf...)

Comment: Thank you. when I used pecl instead of pecl7.2-sp it worked. But the problem with typo3 still remains.

Comment: `sudo pecl install apcu` worked on my machine